# Finding n'th generation in the sequence 1 / 1 1 / 2 1 / 1 2 1 1

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a Haskell program that does as the title says. Basically every cell corresponds to the cell before it, the 2nd cell implies that there is just one '1' in the previous cell, and the 3rd cell implies that there is two '1' in the previous cell and so on.

I'm very new to haskell and to it's syntax so I'm getting loads of errors which aren't helpful so I'm using this forum to get some help with it.

This is my code:

```
findGen :: a -> a
findGen(x) = (getList (x))!!x

getList :: a -> [a]
getList (0) = []
getList (1) = [1]
getList (x) = getList(x-1) : ys where 
                            y = Ord getList(x-1) 
                            zs = group y
                            ds = countify(zs)
                            ys = concat(ds)

group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = (x:ys) : group zs where (ys,zs) = span ((==) x )xs


countify :: [a] -> [a]
countify(x:xs) = (y:xs) where y = count(x)
```

What I was trying to do is like this:
FindGen is just a function that returns the n'th element in the sequence. 
getList is the function that builds the sequence, I was trying to create it using Ord to the previous list so I could group it and then use count to figure out how many times each number appear using countify, and then concating the list making it a string.
Trying to figure out where am I wrong, probably in the syntax because I think the idea is good.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use brackets in function calls or functions, unless you're pattern matching. `findGen(x)` should just be `findGen x` and `ys = countify(zs)` should just be `ys = countify zs`. The only time you need brackets is to pattern match on something like `(x:xs)`, or to do some work before passing it to a function, like you've done in `getList (x-1)`

Comment: Do you mean for this to generate the [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) (1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, 1113213211, …)? The answers so far seem to be solving a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to provide a different thought about it. Consider your list as following,

1. there is a seed `"1"`,
2. To grow the list, you only need to rely on the previous element.

Therefore, it's a fixpoint by looking back to 1 element, which can be implemented by specifying a base case, and the inductive case, then concatenate them.

It results in a two liner.

```
import Data.List (group, sort)

genList :: [String]
genList = "1" : map grow genList
  where grow s = (group $ reverse $ sort s) >>= (\n@(h:_) -> show (length n) ++ [h])

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ take 13 genList
```

Hopefully it's correct,

```
["1","11","21","1211","1231","131221","132231","232221","134211","14131231","14231241","24132231","14233221"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to create it using Ord

If you want to sort a list, use `sort` (from Data.List if I remember correctly)

Also, note that the compiler will not accept `getList` because of the wrong type signature you supplied. Use `Integer` instead of `a` and it will be ok. Fix the signature for `findGen` the same way. Or better yet, until you get more familiar with the type system, don't give type signatures at all.

Furthermore, what is `count`? And why would you need to re-implement `group`?

Comment: Oh, don't mind group, we needed to recreate it as a part of the exercise.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed whatever you guys said, but it still gives me weird errors  main.hs:19:13: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘List’
main.hs:19:21: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘List’

Comment: @The_C It's hard to say what the issue is when we can't see the new code, but List isn't a keyword in Prelude. Keywords with capital letters are generally data constructors, but to make lists we use square brackets to create a list instead of a constructor

Answer (score 0):

If i have the pattern right you may do this by using `Data.Map` and using `iterate` from `Data.List` in a lazy fashion as follows; (Thanks to @luqui's simplification on the map side)

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M
```

```
makeMap :: String -> M.Map Char Int
makeMap cs = foldr incrementOr1 M.empty cs
             where 
             incrementOr1 c m | M.member c m = M.alter (fmap (+1)) c m
                              | otherwise    = M.insert c 1 m
```

```
makeMap :: String -> M.Map Char Int
makeMap = M.fromListWith (+) . map (flip (,) 1)

generateList :: [String]
generateList = iterate getChrCnt "1"
               where
               getChrCnt = M.foldrWithKey (\k n a -> a ++ show n ++ [k]) "" . makeMap

*Main> take 13 $ generateList
["1","11","21","1211","1231","131221","132231","232221","134211","14131231","14231241","24132231","14233221"]
```

Interestingly it doesn't go anywhere beyond the 13th iteration which results "14233221". Just converged.

Comment: `makeMap` is a lot easier than that.  Check out `fromListWith`

Comment: @luqui Hey thanks so much for pointing out `fromListWith`. I was hoping to find out something simpler for this very basic need. I will correct accordingly.